# Which solution is better in production mode. Forking or new Repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I'm managing a project using stash and git. Recently I've seen a new solution for some part of my project. Now I want to apply it as test without affecting my master code and if it would be good enough I add it later to master.
So the problem is Should I make a fork from my project or I have to create new Repository? or Any better solution.

Comment: Do both!  Making a new repository is about as painful as making a copy of a file.  Clone the repo, create a branch, have a working directory available for each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution of your problem is a [branch](http://git-scm.com/about/branching-and-merging). It is the reason they exists, to allow the development of a feature in an isolated context, without affecting the master.

Read more about [branching and merging](http://git-scm.com/about/branching-and-merging).

Answer (score 0):

Since a BitBucket server has [branch permission](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html), you could simply create a branch in the same repo.

But if your new solution involve a large refactoring, and adding that branch to the main repo would bring noise (because it is not related to the main development branches), you can make a fork, in which you can push as many branch as you want without polluting the branch namespace of the main repo.

For an experiment unrelated with the development tasks at hand, I would go with a fork.

Comment: My new feature cause lots of files to be removed and some codes be added. But I'm afraid of fork syncing feature and worry about unintended fault in master repos

Comment: No you control the sync, so no problem there

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to branch from master and do the changes in this new branch.
This branch can be merged in the master anytime as per needs.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for a test I suggest a branch. A fork is usually more suitable when you are collaborating among different teams in a company or if open source then to make your changes and submit a pull request.

Just don't merge the test without making sure it works as needed.